# How to run a function just before the form post happens?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, action

I have a form which posts some data to the server

```
    <form action="action.html" method="post" id="formComments">

    // controls, etc

    </form>
    <script>

function validateFormJustBeforePost()
{
//
return true;
}
</script>
```

Just before the form is posted, I'd like to run a script which returns true or false.
If true it should continue with the post, otherwise not (an error message will be shown)

The form post can happen on clicking a button inside or outside (page menu) the form above.

How to achieve that?

I ran the below but it never alerts:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('form').submit( function()
{
  alert("Something");
});
```

});

Comment: Is this form present in html page?

Comment: what i meant to know is if this is a html or aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` event handler, for example

```
<form onsubmit="return validateFormJustBeforePost()" ... >
```

or in `<script>`:

```
document.getElementById('formComments').onsubmit = validateFormJustBeforePost;
```

or, the most proper way

```
function validateFormJustBeforePost(e){
    if( invalid ){
       e.preventDefault()
       return false;
    }
}
document.getElementById('formComments').addEventListener( 'submit', validateFormJustBeforePost);
```